# Google Drive: Catch events during authentication

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm developing a Windows desktop application that communicates with the user's Google Drive account. I've successfully created the application and its working perfectly fine, just the way I wanted. I followed the tutorial on this website: http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/

But one thing I couldn't figure out is how to catch the events from the authentication process. When the `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` kicks open the web browser to allow the user to authenticate, if the user clicks Cancel to disallow, then the API throws error. That's how I know authentication didn't go through.

But when the user closes the browser window instead of clicking cancel, my application keeps stuck awaiting user's response. How do I catch events when user closes the browser window so that my app can continue with its flow.

Thanks.

Comment: On a webapp, you open the new tab with owner being current tab so you get notified when it closes. Dont know about the csharp browser window open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way. Instead of trying to catch events from Google's OAuth API, its best to write an OAuth authentication yourself. I created a winform in c# containing webbrowser and did all communication and user consent through that. So if user closes the window I would know.

Reference http://www.daimto.com/google-api-and-oath2/